# Bokeh callback to select points similar to user selection

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I'm using Bokeh (Python) to plot a timeseries of the value of well known climate indices (e.g. El Niño) throughout history.

The x-axis in my chart is time, specifically month/year. The y-axis is the analyzed value of the index.

The Tap tool that's built in to Bokeh allows me to select a point in the timeseries and have it highlight.

What I'd like to accomplish on top of that functionality is to have a callback that will highlight other points in the timeseries where the index value is equal to the point that I select through the tap tool.

My biggest problem here is that I don't know JavaScript at all (I'm just a Python-er), so I'd like to avoid having to spend hours learning JavaScript just to write a 5 line callback function.

Anyone have suggestions or code snippets that might accomplish this?

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: The term you're looking for is linked brushing.

Comment: Oh really? I seem to remember seeing something in the docs or on here about linked brushing so I'll look in to that. Helps to have the right terminology. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, to select points from within a callback, you need to update the `selected` property of a `ColumnDataSource` object that is used to create the plot, and is also passed as argument to the callback. As in:

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, TapTool
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=df.x, y=df.y))
p=figure(tools="reset,tap")
p.circle("x", "y", source=source)
cb_click = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    l_selected=source.selected
    // create an array idx that contains the indices of the points you want to select
    l_selected['1d'].indices=idx
    source.selected=l_selected
""")
p.add_tools(TapTool(callback=cb_click))
p.show()
```

Comment: I'm sorry to take so long to reply! I'm going to give this a shot and see what happens. Will report back and accept answer if it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can also write a python callback for the glyph. Below is an example for a circle glyph. By clicking on one of the points you select all points sharing the same y-value.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
import pandas as pd

TOOLS = ["tap"]
p = figure(title="Some Figure", tools=TOOLS)

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                        'y': [11, 12, 13, 15, 15, 11, 12, 11, 15]
                       })
source = ColumnDataSource(dict(df))

pglyph = p.circle(x='x', y='y', source=source)


def callback(attr, old, new):
    try:
        selections = new.indices
        select_inds = [selections[0]]
        if len(selections) == 1:
            selected_issuer = source.data['y'][selections[0]]
            for i in range(0, len(source.data['x'])):
                if i != selections[0]:
                    issuer = source.data['y'][i]
                    if issuer == selected_issuer:
                        select_inds.append(i)
        if len(selections) == 0:
            for i in range(0, len(source.data['x'])):
                select_inds.append(i)
        new.indices = select_inds
    except IndexError:
        pass 


pglyph.data_source.on_change('selected', callback)

curdoc().add_root(column(p))
```

Note that you should use bokeh server to run this.